# como mantener una clase agregada con javascript cuando cambio de seccion?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

tengo una pagina que oculta el footer si el usuario lo desea mediante un boton (que al clickearlo) agrega una clase con js. esto funciona perfecto. 
Pero cuando cambio de sección se elimina la clase y el footer vuelve a estar visible (y el usuario debe volver a ocultarlo) como podría mantener el estado del footer de una sección a la otra? paso código para que vean lo que tengo,
gracias

```js
function footer() {
  document.getElementById("footer").classList.toggle("esconde");
}
```

```css
footer {
  background: #808080;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 280px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px; /* -153px a 0px ----al ocultar footer -------*/
  display: block;
  font-family: 'encodeSemiBold';
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}


/*-----ocultar el footer-------*/

footer.esconde {
  bottom: -153px;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}


/*-----------boton esconde footer----------*/

footer #botonBaja {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #EC2894;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

footer #botonBaja:after {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: '\e906';
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition-duration: .6s;
}

footer #botonBaja.esconde:after,
footer #botonBaja.esconde:focus:after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transition-duration: .6s;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="" onClick="footer()">
  <div id='botonBaja' class=""></div>
  <nav id="menuFooter">
    <ol>
      <li><a href="nuestra_meta.php">Nuestra meta</a></li>
      <li><a href="diseno_responsive.php">Web adaptables</a></li>
      <li><a href="catalogo_online.php">Catálogo online</a></li>
      <li><a href="tienda_virtual.php">Tienda virtual</a></li>
      <li><a href="blogs.php">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="diseno_grafico.php">Diseño gráfico</a></li>
      <li><a href="planes.php">Nuestros planes</a></li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
  <div class="redes">
    <a id="whatsapp" class="" href="#"><img src="imagenes/whatsapp.png" alt="enviar mensaje whatsapp"></a>
    <a id="facebook" href="#"><img src="imagenes/face.png" alt="ingresar a facebook"></a>
    <a id="compartir" href="#"><img src="imagenes/compartir.png" alt="compartir enlace"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="contacto">
    <div id="celu"></div>
    <div id="mail"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hay varias opciones tienes que mantener ese dato(que el usuario ocultó el footer) puede ser indexDB, si tienes bakend, o incluso poner un parametro en la url este ultimo se borrara si el usuario abandona tu pagina. En fin la manera que prefieras de mantener ese dato y luego leerlo.

Comment: exacto!, a eso es a lo que me refiero, pero no tengo idea de como se logra...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que tiene un método que te hace el cambio de sección verdad? Dentro de este método usar el `sessionStorage` (permite guardar datos en la memoria del navegador).

```js
function footer() {
  //Escodemos el footer, guardamos una variable en sessionStorage
  document.getElementById("footer").classList.toggle("esconde"),
  document.getElementById("botonBaja").classList.toggle("esconde");
  //MODIFICADO
  if(document.getElementById("footer").className == "esconde"){
    sessionStorage.setItem("footer", "Ocultado");
  }else{
    sessionStorage.setItem("footer", "Muestra");
  }
}


//Comprobamos si el footer fue ocultado anteriormente por el usuario
//Si fue ocultado, lo ocultamos otravez
//IMPORTANTE esto se debe ejecutarse cuando la pagina se carga al redirigirse, sea 
//nuestra_meta.php o otra, no antes, por eso
//lo ponemos dentro de window.onload, asi obligamos que se ejecute una vez el documento es cargado
//
window.onload = function(){
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('footer') !== "Muestra"){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('footer') == "Ocultado"){
      footer();
    }
  }
}
```

Por que `sessionStorage`? Porque solo te guardara la variable cuando el cliente este en tu paginar, una vez que cierre el navegador, esta variable se destruirá. La próxima vez que entres, el footer se mostrara. Si quieres que la variable persista sustituye `sessionStorage` por `localStorage`

Espero que te sirva

Comment: el cambio de secciones se realiza con el "menu footer" que coloque en el codigo, no utilizo una funcion, sino "<a href=' #'>" para direccionar... probe colorar un "onClick" en <a> para ejecutar  "cambioSeccio()" pero no funciono... debe estar faltandome algo o algo no lo estoy haciendo bien...

Comment: entiendo. Modificare mi respuesta. Revisalo

Comment: pon el codigo que revisa si el footer esta ocultado  o no dentro de `window.onload = function(){if(sessionStorage.getItem('footer') == "Ocultado") footer();}`

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, pero ahora lo que hace es ocultar siempre el footer... cada sección que selecciono la carga con el footer visible y automaticamente lo oculta. no guarda el estado anterior (si estaba abajo o arriba) en la sección anterior... y ni idea cual es el error lo que nunca lo he hecho jajaja... necesitas que te pase algo mas del código para ver que esta pasando??

Comment: no estoy usando ninguna libreria de jquery, por si es eso lo que esta faltando???

Comment: Si. Si me podrias añadir tu codigo lo veria mejor y te podria ayudar :) (me haria falta la función que te abre el footer)

Comment: la función de js que oculta y muestra el footer cuando se cliquea esta en la pregunta.... te la paso de nuevo así no la buscas ;)  `function footer() {
  document.getElementById("footer").classList.toggle("esconde");}` esta función agrega y quita la clase "esconde". ese cambio es el que necesito que se guarde cuando el usuario cambia de sección en la pagina para que no tenga que volver a ocultarlo cada vez que cambie de pagina... muchas gracias por tu interés en mi problema :)

Comment: Buenas. Verifica la respuesta ahora, sobretodo el apartado donde pone modificado.

Comment: Ahora si!!, funciono perfecto. Mil gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionase!

Answer (score 0):

Guardando una variable en localstorage:

`localStorage.setItem("footer", "no");`

Y leyendola al cargar la pagina para desactivar o no el footer:

`localStorage.getItem("footer")`

Amplio:
Te pongo como lo podrias hacer, con una funcion que guarde el estado del footer cuando el user abandona (o cierra) la pagina y otra que chequee el estado guardado al arrancar la pagina

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
localStorage.back_footer = footer;
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 if (localStorage.back_footer==1) {
 document.getElementById("footer").classList.add("esconde");
footer=1;
 };
 });
```

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, creo que es lo que estaba buscando... pero podes ampliarla un poco (soy nueva en js) en que parte o archivo debería generar la variable?

Comment: hola, podrias revisar la sintaxis? xq cuando coloco tu codigo me tira la consola: " SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')' " y se anula la funcion de esconder que ya tenia funcionando

Comment: Si, habia un error con los corchetes de cierre, ya deberia ir bien, de todas formas es solo un ejemplo rapido, tendrias que adaptarlo a tus necesidades